# SOQL query FeedItem by community

Tags: soql, chatter, community, sosl

I would like to query feed items on a specific community, but can't figure out how to do so in SOQL.

For example, this query returns no results.

```
SELECT Id,Body,NetworkScope
FROM FeedItem
WHERE NetworkScope='123123123123123'
```

According to some documentation ([SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) - my question isn't specific to the SOAP API, I'm just pointing this out), the NetworkScope field cannot be used in filters, so I understand why the above query won't work, but I can't figure out what the correct query would be.

For SOSL queries, I found documentation on [WITH NETWORK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_with_network_id.htm) that does work, but I can't find any equivalent for SOQL, and since SOSL requires a text string to search I can't just use that instead.

Is the type of query I want possible?

Comment: Have you looked at the ConnectApi? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm

Comment: In this case I'm restricted to using SOSL/SOQL, thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3J1AAK

Until this is fixed,

> Workaround
>
> Remove the filter out of the SOQL query and filter in code.

Leaving your SOQL as you had originally formulated it.

```
SELECT Id,Body,NetworkScope FROM FeedItem
```

or SOSL:

```
FIND {query} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING FeedItem(id, body, Networkscope)
```

+
Custom Logic on the results to filter on NetworkScope