# Display Community collaboration group announcements using LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, customer-community, feeditem, chatter-feed

In our ORG, we use both Salesforce and Customer Community Plus licenses. Its not a public community. You need to login to access any pages on our site.

I built LWC Component (apiVersion: 47.0) to display all unexpired announcements from the collaboration groups a user is a part of.

When logged in as a Salesforce Cloud license user, I am able to *successfully* retrieve all the Group Announcements without any issues.

When logged in as Customer Community Plus license user, with access to the same groups as the Salesforce cloud license user, the component does not display any results.

I am using @wire service to get the data. I imported Apex Class and the User Information (UserInfo.getUserId()) is determined within the Apex Class along with Network Information (Network.getNetworkId()).

Why does it only display results if it's a Salesforce Cloud License User and not as a Customer Community Plus User?

Comment: Is it because of the filter in SOQL query? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148137/soql-query-feeditem-by-community

Comment: If its true, why does it only affect Customer Community Plus license users?

Answer (score 0):

The issue Customer Community Plus users cannot see multiple group announcements is because of Implementation restriction.

```
> FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: Implementation restriction:
> Announcement requires a filter by an ID, FeedItemId or ParentId using
> the equals operator.
```